# How to pass dynamic form inputs (asp:TextBox) correctly

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have a page that looks like this:

```
Head and body tags...

<form runat="server">
    <ul>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" id="reqUser" controltovalidate="Username" errormessage="<li>There is no username!</li>" />
        More validators...
    </ul>

    <h3><span style="color: Red;">*</span>Username</h3>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="Username" /></br>
    More textboxes...
</form>
```

The thing is, I discovered that based on the id from the `<asp:Textbox />`, the names are created, but with a strange format (`id=" MainContent_originalID"` and `name="ctl00$MainContent$originalID"`)

For me it is ok to have it submit the form to itself. The code works to handle that. The problem is, I don't know if when I use `Request.Form["Name"]` I have to use the original ID or the suplied name after processing. What to I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe in the code you do have to use the supplied name after processing. But, I think there may be a way to get that name based on the original name.

Something like:

```
originalName.ClientID
```

See: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/95796/How-to-get-the-id-name-of-the-ASP-NET-server-contr

**P.S.** You have to use the original ID name with the statement (controllName.UniqueID)